# Getting ASP.NET session value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session-variables

im trying call a session variable stored in c#. My code is

```
var sesion_values= '<%= Session["userEmail"].ToString() %>';
console.log("sesion is: ", sesion_values);
```

this return:

```
sesion is:  <%= Session["userEmail"].ToString() %
```

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags to your question (this problem doesn't involve jquery).

Comment: Use template string literals `var session_values = \`<% : ${Session["userEmail"].toString()} %>\``

Comment: Do note that `<%= ...>` is a server side construct that should be gone (replaced by the value) by the time this line arrives at the browser. But for that it needs server-side processing in a .aspx or .ascx file. So where exactly do these lines of code live?

Comment: apparently is not run - probably you have it inside the .js file that is not been compiled by asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see the asp.net code is not run, so you probably place it inside the javascript file - where asp.net not compile it.

One trick is to add it on .aspx page (or on master page) just before you load the javascript file...

for example, inside the asp.net code do this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var sesion_values = '<%=Session["userEmail"].ToString()%>';
    </script>
    <script src="yourscript.js"></script>    
</head>
```

then you can use the `sesion_values` inside the javascript file.